# TypeError: testing.TestBed.inject is not a function ( jestjs with spectator )

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, angular-spectator

I have this error when i run one test. I use jestjs with spectator to test my angular service

```
it('url path exist', () => {
    expect(spectator.service.getPath).toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: Are you using `inject()` explicitly anywhere?